# Open app as a browser with custom filter

Tags: android, browser

I want to use my app as a browser but ONLY if the link is from an image (jpg, png, jpeg...).

I know I can filter by `hosts` but I don't know if I can filter by file extension.

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: `mimeType` doesn't work with `http/https` urls.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mimeType filter into your intent filter.

something like this:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also you can use * as wild card for the subtype matches

ref: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to obtain the touched url inside my app? (I want the internet image to be shown in an ImageView)

Comment: yes, with `String data = getIntent().getDataString();`
you will get the url

Comment: @pabloblu Thanks again, but the problem is that I want to start a Service when the link is touched, not an Activity. Can I do that? (I've edited my question)

Comment: yes, I think it's possible due services also can contain intent-filters
 http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: @pabloblu I'll check it out!

Comment: @pabloblu It doesn't work like this:

`<data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="image/*" />
 <data android:scheme="https" android:mimeType="image/*" /> `

But if I remove mimeType it works correctly.

Comment: what is url are you using?